# Database design to hold multiple iteration measurements

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlite

I am new to sqlite and SQL in general. I am keen to switch from flat-files to sqlite for holding some measurement information. I need a tip on how to better layout the database, since I have zero experience with this.

I have a ~10000 unique statistic counters that are collected before and after each test iteration. Max number of iterations are 10, though it could be less.

I was thinking the following:

```
CREATE TABLE stat_names(stat_id, stat_name);
CREATE TABLE stats_per_iteration(stat_id, before_iter_1, after_iter_1, before_iter_2, after_iter_2, ...);
```

stat_names table would hold mapping of a full counter to a uniq stat_id. stats_per_iteration table would hold mesurement data 1 + 10 * 2 columns. stat_names.stat_id = stats_per_iteration.stat_id

OR maybe I should have a separate table for each iteration? Which would results in 1 + 10 tables in database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may get you started. Your **stat_names** is called **Measurement** and **stats_per_iteration** would be the  **Iteration** table. The **Test** table would have one entry for each test performed -- like for new device, new day etc.

[image: test_stats_model_01]

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your needs, which really are not addressed in your question.  When designing tables look at these factors, in no particular order:

- how will you write the data
- how will you read the data
- will space be an issue

These can determine their order of importance:

- how many times will you read the data, many or few?
- will you need to make writes with a high frequency?
- how complex are your read queries?
- will the data fit in the space you have?

Based on those, design your structure to make your life easy. In general:

- If you have no space to store it, design it so it will fit
- If you need fast writes, design it so you can output many rows quickly (simple flat design)
- if you have to manipulate and analyze the data a lot, store it in a way that makes that easy.